# procedures in mySql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm actually trying to insert value into table using a procedure.This is my table code

```
create table employeeTable(
    employeeId varchar(20),
    employeeName varchar(20),
    qualification varchar(20),
    cadre varchar(15),
    age numeric(3),
    sex char(1),
    occupation varchar(10),
    dateOfBirth date,
    address varchar(50),
    city varchar(15),
    employeePhoto blob,
    constraint pk_employeeId_employeeTable primary key(employeeId)
    );
```

My insert procedure is

```
    delimiter //
    create procedure insertEmployee(in employeeId varchar(20),in employeeName varchar(20),
    in qualification varchar(20),in cadre varchar(15),in age numeric(3),in sex char(1),
    in occupation varchar(10),in dateOfBirth date,in address varchar(50),in city varchar(15),
    in employeePhoto blob)
    begin
    insert into employeetable values(upper(employeeId),employeeName,qualification,
    cadre,age,sex,occupation,
    str_to_date(dateOfBirth,'%d-%m-%Y'),address,city,employeePhoto);
    end;//
    delimiter ;
```

And I'm trying to call this procedure with following parameters

```
    call insertEmployee('A001','Murugan','Phd','Manager',12,'M','service','30-07-1994',
    '30,PNG nagar,pollachi','Coimbatore',null);
```

But values are not getting inserted and it's showing an error #1048 - Column 'dateOfBirth' cannot be null..
What is the problem here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delimiter //
create procedure insertEmployee(in employeeId varchar(20),in employeeName varchar(20),
in qualification varchar(20),in cadre varchar(15),in age numeric(3),in sex char(1),
in occupation varchar(10),in dateOfBirth varchar(15),in address varchar(50),in city varchar(15),
in employeePhoto blob)
begin
insert into employeetable values(upper(employeeId),employeeName,qualification,
cadre,age,sex,occupation,
str_to_date(dateOfBirth,'%d-%m-%Y'),address,city,employeePhoto);
end;//
delimiter ;
```

Try this procedure. You were accpeting the dateOfBirth as a date object in the parameter list. It should have been a VARCHAR as that is how it is passed to the procedure.